# ¿Cómo realizar una consulta a la BBDD teniendo un array?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo tres tablas: client, project, client_project.

En una vista quiero mostrar todos los proyectos que tiene un cliente.

Adjunto el código que tengo explicado:

```
 public function editClient($id)
    {
        $client = Client::find($id);
        $client_project = DB::table('client_project')->where('client_id',$id)->get(); //obtengo un array con el client_id y project_id de los clientes que coincide el ID con el que he pasado por URL.
        return $client_project; 
       // return view('cms.public.views.clients.editclient')->withClient($client);
    }
```

Ahora sería necesario mostrar el nombre de los proyectos que coincide el campo id de la tabla project con el campo project_id del array $client_project.

Pongo el ejemplo de como se haria si fuera un unico valor, por si puede ayudar.

```
 public function editClient($id)
    {
        $client = Client::find($id);
        $client_project = DB::table('client_project')->where('client_id',$id)->first()->project_id;
        $project = DB::table('projects')->where('id',$client_project)->first();
        return $project;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumo que es una relación "many-to-many", por lo cual deberías tener las relaciones definidas en cada modelo:

Client:

```
/**
 * The projects that belong to the client.
 */
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project');
}
```

Project:

```
/**
 * The clients that belong to the project.
 */
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Client');
}
```

Entonces simplemente cargas la relación previamente con Eager Loading y la accedes como propiedad dinámica y ahí tendrás todos los proyectos del cliente:

```
public function editClient($id)
{
    $projects = Client::with('projects')->find($id)->projects;
    return view('cms.public.views.clients.editclient', compact('projects'));
}
```

El código anterior no lo he probado, por lo cual puede que no funcione, de ser así, intenta con `where()` en vez de `find()`.

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa, utilizando query builder, es hacer el join con la tabla *project*.

Te debería quedar algo así:

```
$client_project = DB::table('client_project')
    ->join('projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'client_project.project_id')
    ->select('client_project.*', 'projects.name')
    ->where('client_project.client_id',$id)
    ->get();
```

Con eso debería funcionar.

Agregué también la sentencia select, para mostrar todos los campos de *client_project* (como lo hacía hasta ahora), y solo el campo *name* de la tabla *projects*.

Al hacer un join y trabajar con más de una tabla, es importante anteponer el nombre de la tabla correspondiente, es cada uno de los campos que se utiliza en la consulta.

Saludos